# Why does the ESPO CRM installer give me a error message

Tags: php, mysql, crm

I have setup the Espo CRM successfully on my localhost. However, I am having issues when trying to install it on my live server. Here is the error message I am recieving. [image]

On the database installation screen when clicking next, it just says 'Some errors occurred!'.
I have checked the phpinfo, and also made sure I have proper permissions on the directory. I have also verified that the MySQL credentials are correct. You would think the error message would have been more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the solution. The issue was mcrypt was not enabled. To enable it, just simply do this:

```
$sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

and then restart Apache

```
$sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Daniel. Had the same problem and couldn't find solution.